# Apache Spark 3.4.0 breaks on Java 17 with "cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer"

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark, rdd

My code in Eclipse I have created Maven project-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", "root");
    props.setProperty("password", "root");
    props.setProperty("driver", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("NameFilteringApp").setMaster("local");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

    JavaRDD<String> namesRDD = JdbcRDD.create(sc,
            ()->DriverManager.getConnection(url, props),
            "select name from test", 1, 100, 2,
            (ResultSet rs)->rs.getString("name"));  
    
    JavaRDD<String> filteredNamesRDD = namesRDD.filter(name ->name.startsWith("D"));
    
    List<String> filteredNames = filteredNamesRDD.collect();
    System.out.println(filteredNames);
    
    
}
```

pom.xml -

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Output in console with Exception -
`Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j2-defaults.properties 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.4.0 23/05/09 13:09:36 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO ResourceUtils: ============================================================== 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver. 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO ResourceUtils: ============================================================== 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: NameFilteringApp 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0) 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: sankarsh.b 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: sankarsh.b 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:  23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:  23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: sankarsh.b; groups with view permissions: EMPTY; users with modify permissions: sankarsh.b; groups with modify permissions: EMPTY 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 49985. 23/05/09 13:09:36 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker 23/05/09 13:09:37 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster 23/05/09 13:09:37 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information 23/05/09 13:09:37 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x5afa3c9) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x5afa3c9     at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala:213)  at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:114)     at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:358)     at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:295)    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:344)    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:196)   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:279)     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:464)     at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)     at one.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:24)`

I am using javaSE-17 and jdk 17

I added this "--add-exports java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED" in jvm arguments but it didnt work

How to solve this?

Comment: Please use code block formatting for errors and logs.

Comment: Why do you use RDD API for that?